# Get the members of ExecutionPolicy in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a utility that will be extensible and not hard code the various types of execution policies. Using Get-Command I can get some information about Set-ExecutionPolicy but I cannot get the members of parameter type Microsoft.Powershell.ExecutionPolicy

```
(get-command set-executionpolicy).parameters.executionpolicy
```

Thats about as far as I've gotten. I've tried using get-typedata but it returns nothing when passing Microsoft.Powershell.ExecutionPolicy to it.

So the question is: How do I enumerate all of the execution policy types?

Comment: `(get-command set-executionpolicy).parameters.executionpolicy.ParameterType.GetEnumNames()`

Comment: I was so close, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

#1- interacting with the enum object properties:

```
[Microsoft.PowerShell.ExecutionPolicy] | Get-Member -Static -MemberType Property
```

---

```
   TypeName: Microsoft.PowerShell.ExecutionPolicy

Name         MemberType Definition
----         ---------- ----------
AllSigned    Property   static Microsoft.PowerShell.ExecutionPolicy AllSigned {get;}
Bypass       Property   static Microsoft.PowerShell.ExecutionPolicy Bypass {get;}
Default      Property   static Microsoft.PowerShell.ExecutionPolicy Default {get;}
RemoteSigned Property   static Microsoft.PowerShell.ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned {get;}
Restricted   Property   static Microsoft.PowerShell.ExecutionPolicy Restricted {get;}
Undefined    Property   static Microsoft.PowerShell.ExecutionPolicy Undefined {get;}
Unrestricted Property   static Microsoft.PowerShell.ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted {get;}
```

#2- introduced in v3, interacting with the enum itself *(this is a shorter version of what @PetSerAl commented)*:

```
                                            # Values()
[Microsoft.PowerShell.ExecutionPolicy].GetEnumNames()
```

---

```
Unrestricted
RemoteSigned
AllSigned
Restricted
Restricted
Bypass
Undefined
```

Pre-v3:

```
         # Names()
[Enum]::GetValues('Microsoft.PowerShell.ExecutionPolicy')
```